# Postgres Unhandled rejection error: relation "public.role" does not exist

Tags: node.js, postgresql, loopbackjs

I am trying to connect to postgresql through Node.JS (LoopBack framework) in windows but when I try to access the database this error will occur:

```
Unhandled rejection error: relation "public.role" does not exist
at Connection.parseE (\node_modules\pg\lib\connetion.js:569:11)
at Connection.parseMessage (\node_modules\pg\lib\connection.js:396:17)
at Socket.<anonymous> (\node_modules\pg\lib\connection.js:132:22)
at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:176:18)
at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:134:10)
at TCP.onread (net.js:548:20)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As one of the pg module developer said:

*"It looks like you're trying to query a table "role" that doesn't exist in the database you're connecting to."*

Answer (score 0):

That looks like invalid escaping for schema + table. What you probably wanted was: `"public"."role"`, as in schema + table, and not `"public.role"` as a table name.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How should I solve this? I thought this is related to some kind of access control...